# How to deserialize object that can be an array or a dictionary with Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json.net

I am using an API that returns a json object that I need to deserialize. My problem is that one of the members of those object is sometimes an empty array ("[]") and sometimes a dictionary ("{"1":{...}, "2":{...}}"). I want to deserialize it into either an array or a dictionary, since I don't car about the IDs, I just want a list of all the objects. Here is how I deserialize the object:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
```

And here is the definition of the Response class:

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "variations")]
    public Dictionary<int, Variation> Variations { get; set; }
}
```

It works well when the Response contains a dictionary in it's variations field, but it fails when it contains an empty array. I'm getting an error from Newtonsoft saying that an array cannot be deserialized into a dictionary. If I define the Variations property as an array, it works for empty arrays, but it fails when it is a dictionary. What could I do to either deserialize correctly both possible values, or to ignore empty arrays and set Variations to null when it's an array instead of failing.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what a bum source :( I bet it is coming from PHP, huh?

Comment: I have seen suggestions to "text replace before converting", but I think it could also be done via a custom JsonConverter.

Comment: @pst : That's a great idea, did't think of doing that.

Comment: If referring to the text replace, I don't think I'd call it "great", but perhaps "hack-ish and working in a pinch". It is easy to imagine degenerate data .. if in .NET4 I believe it would be possible to use `dynamic` with a wrapper accessor (but I do not use .NET4 or dynamic).

Comment: @pst : It's true that it's a hack, but I don't see when changing [] for {} might alter the data. As for the dynamic keyword, it does deserialize, but I'm not very familiar with how I can use the object afterwards.

Comment: @pst : By the way, if you post an answer regarding the use of dynamic, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Should be able to do something like `IDictionary<..,..> Variations { get { return (_variations is IList /* Array or List but not Dictionary */) ? new Dictionary<..,..>() : (IDictionary<..,..>)_variations; } }`. Just post the solution you ended up using :) Also, will it work with just `object` and not `dynamic` for the mapped `_variation` property?

Comment: As for the text-replace solution: `{foo: "string that contains things like variations=[] that should be left alone"}`. Granted the input may never be as such, but .. one day, somewhere, this, or something similar, will jump up and bite you.

Comment: It will probably work with just object instead of dynamic. I'll try that on Tuesday (I won't be at work before then) and let you know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I used :

```
    public Dictionary<int, Variation> Variations
    {
        get
        {
            var json = this.VariationsJson.ToString();
            if (json.RemoveWhiteSpace() == EmptyJsonArray)
            {
                return new Dictionary<int, Variation>();
            }
            else
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, Variation>>(json);
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "variations")]
    public object VariationsJson { get; set; }
```

Basically, the variations are first deserialized in a basic object. When I want to read the value, I check if the object is an empty array, and if so I return an empty dictionary. If the object is a good dictionary, I deserialize it and return it.

Answer (score 9):

Here an alternative solution using JsonConverter

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "variations")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EmptyArrayOrDictionaryConverter))]
    public Dictionary<int, Variation> Variations { get; set; }
}


public class EmptyArrayOrDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            return token.ToObject(objectType, serializer);
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            if (!token.HasValues)
            {
                // create empty dictionary
                return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
            }
        }

        throw new JsonSerializationException("Object or empty array expected");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: GOOD! had been looking everywhere for this. (much better than the string replace hack)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation (sorry for the pun) on Carl's example. I had a similar need, but instead of returning a dictionary, I needed an array. The API I am using says it returns an array. However, in the case where there is only one item in the result, it is returned as an object instead!

```
public class VarationsContainer
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Varation[] Varations
    {
        get
        {
            return ParseObjectToArray<Variation>(VariationObject);
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "varations")]
    public object VarationsObject { get; set; }

    protected T[] ParseObjectToArray<T>(object ambiguousObject)
    {
        var json = ambiguousObject.ToString();
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
        {
            return new T[0]; // Could return null here instead.
        }
        else if (json.TrimStart().StartsWith("["))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(json);
        }
        else
        {
            return new T[1] { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json) };
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is useful to some other sad API consumer.

Comment: +1 Saved me a lot of mucking around thanks. Works perfectly for object / array (in my case ToList()).